# Unable to find docker image locally when running docker run

Tags: docker

As you can see I have the following images

```
vinay@idol-nifi-web-1 ~ $ docker images
    REPOSITORY                                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi                        <none>              0de8fa3d35d4        About an hour ago   5.62GB
    debian                                                latest              e1de74e67cc7        3 days ago          101MB
    gcr.io/gce-containers/konlet                          v.0.9-latest        da64965a2b28        8 months ago        73.4MB
    gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent   0.2-1.5.33-1-1      fcfafd404600        11 months ago       548MB
```

I am trying to run the idol-web-nifi image and it won't run it as it is unable to find the image.

```
vinay@idol-nifi-web-1 ~ $ docker run --mac-address="42:01:0A:98:00:02" -it --entrypoint /bin/bash gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi:latest
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the
 steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See 'docker run --help'
```

.

Comment: Looks like it might be the tag that's wrong, are you able to rebuild and specify 'latest' on the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `latest` tag for this image:

```
REPOSITORY                                            TAG
gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi                        <none>
```

So you have to run it without a tag or tag it:

```
docker run gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi
# or
docker tag gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi:latest
docker run gcr.io/idol-demo/idol-web-nifi:latest
```